# Apache NetBeans 11.1 JavaScript Highlighting Not Working

Tags: javascript, netbeans, netbeans-11

I"m currently using Apache NetBeans 11.1 in Windows 10:

```
Product Version: Apache NetBeans IDE 11.1
Updates: NetBeans IDE is updated to version NetBeans 8.2 Patch 2
Java: 1.8.0_221; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 25.221-b11
Runtime: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 1.8.0_221-b11
System: Windows 10 version 10.0 running on amd64; Cp1252; en_US (nb)
User directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\11.1
Cache directory: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\11.1
```

The IDE seems to support the PHP Netbeans Bundle as it works properly with PHP, CSS, HTML and Twig. However when i try to open a plain JavaScript file (or embed script tags) inside HTML, the JavaScript highlighting doesn't work, the IDE is opening the file as plain text:

[image]

Does anyone know what i need to do to enable the highlighting of JavaScript in Apache NetBeans 11.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to activate the HTML5 plugin.
Select Tools > Plugins to open the NetBeans Plugins manager. Click the Installed tab then select the HTML5 plugin, which I think is installed by default, and click Activate

Comment: How to activate HTML5 plugin? Please provide complete answer.

Comment: Sorry :-) 
Select Tools > Plugins to open the NetBeans Plugins manager. Click the Installed tab then select the HTML5 plugin, which I think is installed by default, and click Activate.

Comment: Please add this to your answer as you are answering OP's question.

Comment: Voilà! Just wondering why isn't this enabled by default nor why doesn't activate itself when opening a JavaScript file. Thanks !